# How to Video stream starting from any point HTTP live streaming

Tags: video-streaming, jwplayer, http-live-streaming, mse

I have done my research and now I have a moderate understanding of how video streaming works and how it differs from audio. Now I use ffmpeg to convert  .Mp4  file to fragmented version(series of .ts and .m3u8 manifest) am using hls.js to play this back on the browser and its working but then for every request it would always start from the beginning. I don't want this. So my question is, how do I start streaming from any point? If I use ffmpeg to cut the video, it will keep creating series of .ts files. And not only that the .m3u8 will also be rewritten. Please how do I resolve this? Am I going the wrong way if yes please point me to the right direction I wud appreciate tnx.

**Update**: I use the following ffmpeg command:

> ffmpeg -i babylon.mp4 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -s 840x560 -start_number 20000 -ss 30 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls babylon.m3u8

Comment: what Is the ffmpeg conmand you are using?

Comment: @szatmary I use the following command ffmpeg -i babylon.mp4 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -s 840x560 -start_number 20000 -ss 30 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls babylon.m3u8

Comment: Please update the question. Try not to use stackoverdlow as forum. It works best  as question/answer not conversation.